# How to make an action by clicking on ScrollView in Tableview Customcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a tableview and i'm using CustomCell for that tableview. I have imageview, label, and ScrollView in that customcell. But my problem is, after clicking image or label that particular cell is selected and then navigating to the detailView. But on clicking scrollview, cell is not selected. How to solve my problem.? Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

My custom cell like below:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution 1

When clicking on the scroll view, cell is not selected because the scroll view receives the touches, not the cell. If you want the cell to receive touches you need to explicitly set,

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

which will make the *scrollView* irresponsive to touches, and I hope that is not what you want.

#### Solution 2

I think you are not doing anything with the *scrollView* when you tap on it. If so, add a *UITapGestureRecognizer* to the *scrollView* and in the *tap action* do the operation that you do in *didSelectRowAtIndexPath:* method.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap { 

    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)tap.view;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)scrollView.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    [self tableView:tbl_view didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
}
```

Comment: If i set like that, then ther is no use of scrollview. Because i need to see entire data if more than 2 values by scrolling. How to do this?

Comment: Yes sir , I did like this: But ho can i get indexpath by this method:                                        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = 
   [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
   singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   [cell.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
   [singleTap release];
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{   

 //[self tableView:tbl_view didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}